# Function name must be a string in Laravel

Tags: laravel

Laravel Framework 5.6.39
I'm getting this error:

```
Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalThrowableError (E_ERROR)
Function name must be a string
```

Here is what I'm doing.  In my `App/RouteServiceProvider.php`

```
public function map()
{
    $this->mapApiRoutes();

    $this->mapWebRoutes();

    $this->mapMercuriusRoutes();
}

protected function mapMercuriusRoutes()
{
  Route::middleware(['web','auth','Mercurius'])
        ->namespace('\Launcher\Mercurius\Http\Controllers')
        ->group(base_path('routes/mercurius.php'));
}
```

Then my route file `mercurius.php`:

```
// Mercurius home
Route::get('/messages', ['as' => 'home', 'uses' => 'MessagesController@index']);
// User Profile
Route::get('/profile/refresh', 'ProfileController@refresh');
Route::get('/profile/notifications', 'ProfileController@notifications');
Route::post('/profile', 'ProfileController@update');
```

When I go to localhost:8000/messages as listed in the Mercurius routes file I get the error.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

EDIT: INITIAL ERRORS:

```
$response = method_exists($pipe, $this->method)
                                ? $pipe->{$this->method}(...$parameters)
                                : $pipe(...$parameters);
```

The $pipe(...$parameters); is the highlighted one.

```
Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError 
…/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php152

Illuminate\Pipeline\Pipeline Illuminate\Pipeline\{closure}
…/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Pipeline.php53

Illuminate\Routing\Pipeline Illuminate\Routing\{closure}
…/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php41
```

Comment: Which specific line throws that error? `->group(base_path('routes/mercurius.php'))` doesn't look like correct syntax.

Comment: $response = method_exists($pipe, $this->method)
                                ? $pipe->{$this->method}(...$parameters)
                                : $pipe(...$parameters); @ceejayoz

Comment: I'm interested in which line of *your* code triggers it. Not the big stacktrace.

Comment: Can you post your Mercurius middleware definition and how you registered it in the RouteServiceProvider?

Comment: It appears that the middleware definition is the problem.  I was expecting it to be auto discovered and installed since I installed the package with composer.  @mdexp

Comment: I posted that as an answer so you can mark the question as solved

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that `Mercurius` middleware is defined and registered correctly in the Route Service Provider.

Answer (score 2):

I think the error is in `group` call. You should use a callback like this:

```
Route::middleware(['web','auth','Mercurius'])
    ->namespace('\Launcher\Mercurius\Http\Controllers')
    ->group(function ($r) {
        require base_path('routes/mercurius.php');
    });
```

Check if it helps.

Comment: Can you edit your question with the initial lines of the error page?

Comment: @FabricioG Try to find in the error page, the first line that points to a file that you edited, if there is any.

Comment: Ok will do @Laerte

Comment: The given group function syntax is fine and allowed by the framework